# Data not send correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

```js
import './App.css';
import OutputBox from './OutputBox';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import * as functions from "./functions.js"
import axios from 'axios'

function App() {
  //define state variables
  const [cargo, setCargo] = useState('');
  const [acceleration, setAcceleration] = useState('');
  const [takeoff_time, setTakeOffTime] = useState('');
  const [takeoff_distance, setTakeOffDistance] = useState('');
  const [excess_cargo, setExcessCargo] = useState('');
  const [date, setDate] = useState();
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');


  //send the data to /insert-data in order to store it in the db
  const insertData = () => {
    axios.post("http://localhost:3001/insert-data", {
      takeoff_time: takeoff_time.toString(),
      takeoff_distance: takeoff_distance.toString(),
      excess_cargo: excess_cargo.toString(),
      cargo: cargo.toString()
  }).then(()=> {
  console.log("success");
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });

  console.log(takeoff_time +" | "+ takeoff_distance+" | "+excess_cargo+" | "+cargo);
};




  //get the cargo data
  //return if the input is valid 
  const validInput = (cargo) => {
    
    if (cargo < 0 || isNaN(cargo)) {
      alert("invalid input!");
      return false;
    }
    else {
      return true;
    }

  }
  
  //A function that centralizes the actions
  const handleData = () => {
    if(validInput(cargo)){

      //update the variables every time it change
      setAcceleration(functions.getAcceleration(cargo));
      setTakeOffTime(functions.getTakeOffTime(cargo));
      setTakeOffDistance(functions.getTakeOffDistance(cargo));
      setExcessCargo(functions.getExcessCargo(cargo));

      //call the insert function
      insertData();
    }

  }

 //asynchronous func to handle the date data
const handleDate = async () => {
  try { //make a post request to send date data to the back-end
    const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/date-picker", { date });
    setMessage(response.data); //set the changed value to the current variable
  }catch(error){ //trying to catch errors
    console.log(error);
  }
  
}


//prints to the web the data
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <div className='data'>

    <h1>Shimshon physics calculator</h1>
    <label>Enter cargo weight:</label>
    <input type="number" onChange={ (event) => {setCargo(event.target.valueAsNumber)}}/>

    <button onClick={handleData}>Send data</button>

    <OutputBox text={`Acceleration: ${acceleration}`} />
    <OutputBox text={`Takeoff Time: ${takeoff_time}`} />
    <OutputBox text={`Takeoff Distance: ${takeoff_distance}`} />
    <OutputBox text={`Excess Cargo: ${excess_cargo}`} />
    

    
    <br />
    <label>Enter flight date:</label>
    <input type= "date" onChange={(event) => { setDate(event.target.value) }} />
    <button onClick={handleDate}>Send date</button>

    <OutputBox text={`you ${ message } able to filght`} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

the problem is when I enter cargo and click send data.
I receive in the table in the db only the entered cargo value, and the other values are empty.
But when I re-enter input for cargo and click on send data I get in the table of the db the value of the current entered cargo and the previous value of (takeoff_time, takeoff_distance, excess_cargo).
any solution pls??

Answer (score 0):

The reason your app behaves like it does has to do with the way states are updated. When calling `insertData` you update 4 states before calling the axios function. States update asynchronously. That means that your app won't wait for the states to have changed before running the rest of your code. So in practice, `insertData` will be called before any of the states have been modified, leaving you with empty values.

The solution lies in the way that you handle changed data. Instead of updating the four states when clicking the button, update them immediately after the `cargo` state has changed.

I'd recommend that you change the acceleration, take off, distance and excess cargo states to into [`useMemo`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useMemo) hooks. This way you'll immediately make the calculations necessary for any future requests without triggering a re-render.

The snippet below is an example of you would implement these practices. I've also added multiple [`useCallback`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useCallback) hooks. Both `useMemo` and `useCallback` will store the result based on the states they're dependant on so that the same calculation doesn't have be to done more than once. This is not mandatory, but an optimization.

```
import './App.css';
import OutputBox from './OutputBox';
import React, { useState, useMemo, useCallback } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import {
  getAcceleration,
  getTakeOffTime,
  getTakeOffDistance,
  getExcessCargo
} from "./functions.js"

function App() {
  const [cargo, setCargo] = useState(0);
  const [date, setDate] = useState();
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  const isValidCargo = useMemo(() => 
    cargo >= 0 && !isNaN(cargo)
  }, [cargo]);

  const acceleration = useMemo(() => 
    getAcceleration(cargo), 
  [cargo]);

  const takeoffTime = useMemo(() => 
    getTakeOffTime(cargo), 
  [cargo]);

  const takeoffDistance = useMemo(() => 
    getTakeOffDistance(cargo), 
  [cargo]);

  const excessCargo = useMemo(() => 
    getExcessCargo(cargo), 
  [cargo]);

  const insertData = useCallback(() => {
    axios.post("http://localhost:3001/insert-data", {
      takeoff_time: takeoffTime.toString(),
      takeoff_distance: takeoffDistance.toString(),
      excess_cargo: excessCargo.toString(),
      cargo: cargo.toString()
    }).then(()=> {
      console.log("success");
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }, [takeoffTime, takeoffDistance, excessCargo, cargo]);

  const handleData = useCallback(() => {
    if (isValidCargo) {
      insertData();
    }
  }, [isValidCargo]);

  const handleDate = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/date-picker", {
        date 
      });
      setMessage(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }, [date]);

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      {/* The rest of your rendered body here */}
    </div>
  );
}
```